# lxml and loops to create xml rss in python

Tags: python, lxml

I have been using lxml to create the xml of rss feed.  But I am having trouble with the  tags and cant really figure out how to to add a dynamic number of  elements.  Given that lxml seems to just have functions as parameters of functions,  I cant seem to figure out how to loop for a dynamic number of items without remaking the entire page.

```
rss = page = (
      E.rss(
        E.channel(
          E.title("Page Title"),
   E.link(""),
   E.description(""),

            E.item(
                  E.title("Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! "),
                  E.link("htt://"),
                  E.description("this is a"),
            ),
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
channel = E.channel(E.title("Page Title"), E.link(""),E.description(""))
    for (title, link, description) in container:
        try:
                    mytitle = E.title(title)
                    mylink = E.link(link)
                    mydesc = E.description(description)
            item = E.item(mytitle, mylink, mydesc)
                except ValueError:
                    print repr(title)
                    print repr(link)
                    print repr(description)
                    raise
        channel.append(item)
    top = page = E.top(channel)
```

Answer (score 6):

Jason has answered your question; but – just FYI – you can pass any number of function arguments dynamically as a list: `E.channel(*args)`, where `args` would be `[E.title(`...`), E.link(`...`),`...`]`. Similarly, keyword arguments can be passed using dict and two stars (`**`). See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 5):

[This lxml tutorial](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#the-element-class) says:

---

To create child elements and add them to a parent element, you can use the `append()` method:

```
>>> root.append( etree.Element("child1") )
```

However, this is so common that there is a shorter and much more efficient way to do this: the `SubElement` factory. It accepts the same arguments as the `Element` factory, but additionally requires the parent as first argument:

```
>>> child2 = etree.SubElement(root, "child2")
>>> child3 = etree.SubElement(root, "child3")
```

---

So you should be able to create the document, then say `channel = rss.find("channel")` and use either of the above methods to add more items to the `channel` element.