# Does the E-factory of lxml support dynamically generated data?

Tags: python, html, lxml

Is there a way of creating the tags dynamically with the E-factory of lxml? For instance I get a syntax error for the following code:

```
E.BODY(
        E.TABLE(
            for row_num in range(len(ws.rows)):
                row = ws.rows[row_num]

                # create a tr tag
                E.TR(
                    for cell_num in range(len(row)):
                        cell = row[cell_num]
```

I get the following error:

```
   for row_num in range(len(ws.rows)):
     ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to create multiple child nodes, pass [multiple positional or keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104751/lxml-and-loops-to-create-xml-rss-in-python).

Working example:

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
from lxml.html import tostring

E = ElementMaker()

body = E.BODY(
    E.TABLE(
        *[E.TR(
            *[
                E.TD("%s %s" % (row_num, col_num)) for col_num in range(3)
            ]
        ) for row_num in range(2)]
    )
)

print tostring(body, pretty_print=True)
```

Prints:

```
<BODY><TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>0 0</TD>
<TD>0 1</TD>
<TD>0 2</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>1 0</TD>
<TD>1 1</TD>
<TD>1 2</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE></BODY>
```

---

As a side note, from what I understand you want to create an HTML file  filled with data coming from a parsed excel file. Instead of making elements with `lxml`, you might better and easier solve it with a template engine like [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) or [`mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I am trying to create an HTML file with data from the excel file. Can you please provide me with a good mako tutorial as a starting point or maybe provide with an example of how I can do it.

Comment: @user3293692 the idea is pretty simple, create the template with pre-defined placeholders and render it with the data coming into the context from an excel file. If you struggle with it, consider making a separate question. But be sure you at least make an attempt to solve it on your own. Thanks. To close this topic, consider marking the answer as accepted.