# Unpack a two-dimensional list through the loop

Tags: python, list, lxml

I have a need of unpacking two-dimensional list (list of lists) with a dynamic length. The whole task is to form a full-featured HTML-table from my list with the help of **lxml** framework.

Having been used [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31143949/911419) as a backbone I came to the following code for my task:

```
 page = (
    E.html(
        E.body(
        E.table(
                E.tr(
                    E.th(E.div("header1")),
                      ...
                    E.th(E.div("header40")),
                    ),
                *[E.tr(
                     *[
                        E.td(str(col)) for col in p_list[1] <<- how to put N here???
                     ]
                    ) for row in range(len(p_list))]
                , border="2"
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

The first `E.tr` is a header for my table, the second one `*[E.tr` is unpacked from the list `p_list`. The list has N elements (aka rows) each of which is a list itself consisting of around 50 elements (aka columns of N row).

The `p_list` is declared and filled like this:

```
p_list = list()
rows = table.iter('div')
p_list.append([c.text for c in rows])
rows = table.xpath("body/table")[0].findall("tr")
for row in rows[2:]:
   p_list.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

Now this code can only output **the same** row of `p_list` N times and works only with a hard-coded row number, but what if I want to specify it dynamically to output the whole table?

Cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `p_list[1]` with `p_list[row]`. Even better, don't use `range`:

```
*[E.tr(
   *[ E.td(str(col)) for col in row ]
) for row in p_list ]
```

Comment: It throws `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list` on the last row.

Comment: Show a complete traceback, please.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/media/Downloads/functions.py", line 206, in to_html
    ) for row in p_list ]
  File "/media/Downloads/functions.py", line 206, in <listcomp>
    ) for row in p_list ]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: Have you made change just to the last line, but not the previous one?